# Is It Safe to Cast Away volatile?

Tags: c++

Most of the time, I am doing this way.

```
class a {
public:
    ~ a() {
        i = 100;          // OK
        delete (int *)j;  // Compiler happy. But, is it safe?
                          // The following code will lead compilation error : delete j;
    }

private:
    volatile int i;
    volatile int *j;
};

int main() {
    a aa;

}
```

However, I saw an article here:

https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/EXP32-C.+Do+not+access+a+volatile+object+through+a+non-volatile+reference

> Casting away volatile allows access to
>   an object through a non-volatile
>   reference. This can result in
>   undefined and perhaps unintended
>   program behavior.

So, what will be the workaround for my above code example?

Here is the error message I get if I use

> delete j

Note that, this is output from VC6 (Don't ask why I am using VC6!)

> c:\projects\a\a.cpp(5) : error C2664:
>   'delete' : cannot convert parameter 1
>   from 'volatile int *' to 'void *'
>   Conversion loses qualifiers

Comment: Why do you think it should be volatile?

Comment: @Richard: A spinlock flag may be allocated in plain memory and yet be volatile. Not that crazy really.

Comment: I don't see why `delete j;` would be a compile time error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing. If you don't access the volatile memory, the semantics of volatile are unaffected. If you accessed volatile memory through a casted non-volatile pointer, the compiler might optimize the reference away. If the value had changed, you'd have the wrong value. For some value of wrong. ;-)

The delete doesn't access the volatile memory, it just frees it. Sort of an uncommon thing to do with volatile memory.

Comment: Well, freeing it grants everyone else access by allowing `new` to return the same memory. So although it might be allowed, it's certainly unsafe if the memory is genuinely volatile.

Comment: Potatoswatter: Right, but freeing volatile memory implies it was new'd in the first place otherwise it's a bad thing. I'm assuming that the allocated memory is somehow volatile. I suspect it isn't really.

Answer (score 3):

`delete`ing a `volatile` would imply that you've serialized access to it so it is not, in fact, `volatile` any more. The proper way to remove the volatile (once you know it's safe) is with `const_cast<int*>`.

If the pointer, and not the `int`, is volatile, then you really meant `int *volatile j`. Moreover, if all the members of a class are volatile, you probably want to qualify the entire object at once, `a volatile aa;`.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the meaning you expect from your volatile variable. Right now, `j` is a pointer to a volatile integer; is that what you mean? If so, it's safe since you don't need to access the volatile value, just its address, which isn't volatile.

If, however, you meant that you want a volatile pointer to an integer, the required syntax is `int* volatile j`. In that case, it could be problematic to cast it to a non-`volatile` pointer first, but I don't think your compiler would complain if you tried to `delete` it as is. G++, for one, doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

That should be fine, since you're not *accessing* the variable after casting away the `volatile`.  However, I don't know why you'd get an error regardless.  I tried that code myself, and everything seemed to go fine, what did you see happen?

Comment: @Yan Cheng CHEOK: yeah, we kind of guessed that. Can you copy/paste the error?

Comment: @Yan, I'm saying there was no compilation error for me. There's not even a warning if I use `-Wall`.