# C/C++: casting away volatile considered harmful?

Tags: c++, c, volatile

(related to this question [Is It Safe to Cast Away volatile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474756/is-it-safe-to-cast-away-volatile), but not quite the same, as that question relates to a specific instance)

**Is there ever a case where casting away `volatile` is *not* considered a dangerous practice?**

(one particular example: if there is a function declared

```
void foo(long *pl);
```

and I have to implement

```
void bar(volatile long *pl);
```

with part of my implementation requiring bar() to call foo(pl), then it seems like I can't get this to work as is, because the assumptions made by the compilation of foo() and the compilation of the caller of bar() are incompatible.)

---

As a corollary, if I have a `volatile` variable v, and I want to call `foo(&v)` with someone else's function `void foo(long *pl)`, and that person tells me it's safe, I can just cast the pointer before the call, my instinct is to tell them they're wrong because there's no way to guarantee that, and that they should change the declaration to `void foo(volatile long *pl)` if they want to support the use of volatile variables. Which one of us is correct?

Comment: `void bar(volatile long* pl) { long x = *pl; foo(&x); *pl = x; }`?

Comment: Why not overload foo to have a volatile friendly version for when it needs to be called by bar?

Comment: @James: No, because the semantics of that volatile variable may not produce correct results. If the `foo()` function is supposed to be an atomic increment, for example, then it's possible to call bar() from two threads and lose one of the increments.

Comment: @AJG85: Because I'm not the author of foo, someone else is.

Comment: @Jason S: In that case either what James said or change bar to use correct convention. Also `volatile` does not provide atomic variables in C++ so that would be insufficient either way.

Comment: insufficient but necessary. Anyway this is an embedded system, and the compiler provides a set of atomic intrinsics but they're not declared using volatile arguments, whereas InterlockedIncrement() in Windows is one that does. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Jason: If the semantics are such that James' solution is not right, then `foo` should probably already be taking a volatile pointer anyway. If for example `foo` is an atomic increment, casting away the `volatile` should be harmless since the atomic operation will already provide stronger guarantees than `volatile` would...

Comment: Fair enough but it's still the memory barrier of that windows API that makes it atomic not the `volatile`. I would rely on the compiler instrinsic over `InterlockedIncrement` or use `std::atomic` if your compiler supports it.

Comment: Why you don't tell us why the parameter is declared `volatile`?

Answer (score 21):

If the variable is **declared** `volatile` then it is **undefined behaviour** to cast away the `volatile`, just as it is undefined behaviour to cast away the `const` from a variable declared `const`. See Annex J.2 of the C Standard:

> The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
>
> ...
>
> — An attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through
>   use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type (6.7.3).
>
> — An attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through
>   use of an lvalue with non-volatile-qualified type (6.7.3).

If, however, you just have a `volatile` pointer or a `volatile` reference to a non-`volatile` variable then you can freely cast away `volatile`.

```
volatile int i=0;
int j=0;

volatile int* pvi=&i; // ok
volatile int* pvj=&j; // ok can take a volatile pointer to a non-volatile object

int* pi=const_cast<int*>(pvi); // Danger Will Robinson! casting away true volatile
int* pj=const_cast<volatile int*>(pvj); // OK
*pi=3; // undefined behaviour, non-volatile access to volatile variable
*pj=3; // OK, j is not volatile
```

Comment: Is it same for c as well?

Comment: I upvoted for the C reference, but I believe there is something incorrect where you have ```volatile int* pvj=&j; // ok can take a volatile pointer to a non-volatile object```.  You are assigning a reference to a non-volatile int to a pointer of a volatile int, so unless that will cause ```j``` to be volatile, I believe there is an issue.  Also, you speak of a volatile pointer, but I don't see any in your code.  A volatile pointer would be something like ```int* volatile``` or ```int volatile* volatile``` (which is equivalent to ```volatile int* volatile```).

Answer (score 9):

Casting away volatile would be ok, once the value is in fact no longer volatile. In SMP/multi-threading situations, this *could* become true after acquiring a lock (and passing a memory barrier, which is most often implicit in acquiring the lock).

So a typical pattern for this would be

```
 volatile long *pl = /*...*/;

 //
 {
      Lock scope(m_BigLock);   /// acquire lock
      long *p1nv = const_cast<long *>(p1);

      // do work
 } // release lock and forget about p1nv!
```

But I could come up with a number of other scenarios in which values stop being volatile. I won't suggest them here, as I'm sure you can come up with them yourself, if you know what you're doing. Otherwise, the locking scenarios seems solid enough to provide as an example

Comment: You need `const_cast` to cast away `volatile`, not `static_cast`.

Comment: +1 for providing enlightenment. Thanks. I hadn't thought about situations like that where there are intervals when volatile variables can have nonvolatile guarantees.

Answer (score 5):

With a signature of `foo(long *pl)`, the programmer is declaring that they are not expecting the pointed-to `long` value to change externally during the execution of `foo`. Passing a pointer to a `long` value that *is* being concurrently modified throughout an invocation might even lead to erroneous behavior if the compiler emits code that dereferences the pointer multiple times due to lack of registers and by it choosing not to store the value of the first dereference on the stack. For example, in:

```
void foo(long *pl) {

    char *buf = (char *) malloc((size_t) *pl);

    // ... busy work ...

    // Now zero out buf:
    long l;
    for (l = 0; l < *pl; ++l) {
        buf[l] = 0;
    }

    free(buf);
}
```

`foo` could overrun the buffer in the "zero out buf" step if the `long` value is increased while the busy work is being performed.

If the `foo()` function is supposed to atomically increment the `long` value pointed to by `pl`, then it would be incorrect for the function to take `long *pl` and not `volatile long *pl` because the function clearly requires that accesses of the `long` value be a sequence point. If `foo()` only atomically incremented, the function might work, but it would not be correct.

Two solutions to this problem have already been suggested in comments:

1. Wrap `foo` taking `long *` in an overload taking `volatile long *`:

   ```
   inline void foo(volatile long *pvl) {
       long l = *pvl;
       foo(&l);
       *pvl = l;
   }
   ```
2. Change the declaration of `foo` to `void foo(volatile long *pvl)`.