# Can you cast away volatile on a member from a volatile function>

Tags: c++, volatile

If you have a class member function marked volatile, is it possible to cast away volatile on a class member when it's bein used within that function?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367580/c-c-casting-away-volatile-considered-harmful

Comment: The real question is why? Do you have code that illustrates a problem that requires you to get rid of the volatile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. To cast away the volatile-ness of an object, `const_cast` is used:

```
T & t = const_cast<T&>(volatile_t);
```

This is the way. But whether you should use it in your code or not, I cannot say without looking at the code. In general, casting away the const-ness as well as volatile-ness, is a dangerous idea, and should be done only after very careful examination of all cases.

Comment: As with any const-cast, you can expect undefined behaviour if you don't honour the contract provided by the constness or volatility guarantee. The cast is only to be used as a work-around for otherwise fixed code; for example, if you know that a function isn't modifying a reference, but is declared with a non-const reference anyway. Const-cast does *not* magically create a mutable object!

Answer (score 0):

You can cast away `volatile` from any context by using `const_cast`. You are asking precisely about casting away inside a `volatile` member, but that does not make any difference.

The `volatile` in the function is a check that tells the compiler not to complain if you try to call that method on a `volatile` object (or through a reference or pointer to `volatile` object), which is unrelated to the `volatile`-ness of the members.

What I am trying to say is that if you expect the behavior while accessing data members to be consistent with `volatile` semantics *just because* the code is inside a `volatile` member method, that won't happen.