# 'while' loop optimised too much - why does the nop() fix it?

Tags: c

I am trying to figure out why after turning the compiler optimisation on the following code stopped working:

```
bool send_atcmd(char* atcmd, char* expected_response, unsigned int timeout)
{
    volatile char* buf = uart_get_rx_buf(UART_MODEM);
    bool response_match = false;
    if (modem_powered_on)
    {
        __delay_cycles((unsigned long)500 * DELAY_MS);
        uart_clear_rx_buf(UART_MODEM);
        uart_puts(UART_MODEM, atcmd);
        uart_putc(UART_MODEM, '\r');
        timer_ms = 0;
        while (!response_match && timer_ms <= timeout)
        {
            //__nop();                                  
            if (strstr(buf, expected_response) != NULL)
                response_match = true;
        }
        uart_clear_rx_buf(UART_MODEM);
    }
    return response_match;
}
```

The code is compiled with msp430-gcc, *buf* points to receive buffer of uart port where modem operates. Everything works ok until there is no optimisation (-O0), but when turning the optimisation on the *while* loop is finished when the `timer_ms <= timeout`  condition is false, the `strstr(buf, expected_response)` never returns !NULL. This is because the contents of the buf does not seem to be updated.

But, anything put right before
`if (strstr(buf, expected_response) != NULL)` in the while loop, like e.g uncommenting the nop() makes the code work properly.

The `buf` is updated in ISR.

Why does even the __nop() helps?

Comment: Sort of unrelated, but it is generally bad to busy-wait; you should let the thread sleep for a millisecond or so each loop.

Comment: @Dave, ok, that is what nop() will do (thread sleep), but what happens in the background?

Comment: @Dave - 'msp430' - it's a toaster-controller.

Comment: where is `timer_ms` defined? Important to know whether it is `volatile`

Comment: @MattMcNabb, it's an extern, in the file where the analyzed `while` loop is: `volatile extern unsigned int timer_ms`. It 's updated by the timer interrupt service routine. But anyway, it doesn't seem to be a problem with `timer_ms` as the while correctly exits upon false condition.

Comment: If this is running on reduced hardware, could this thread simply be blocking the writer thread? Or is the writer interrupt-driven?

Comment: Also if you suspect an optimiser bug, you could try making buf `volatile char* volatile` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @Dave, sure already put lots of `volatile`s, didn't help

Comment: Have to ask the obvious question: `modem_powered_on` is true, right? (And set in this thread or volatile?)

Comment: is 'uart_get_rx_buf' guaranteed to always return a null-terminated string?

Comment: @Dave, yes, it's set and accessible. The code enters the `if (modem_powered_on)` branch but not to `if (strstr(buf, expected_response) != NULL)`

Comment: Quacks like an invariant code motion optimization bug to me, hoisting the strstr() call out of the loop.  You'll have to look at the generated machine code to nail it down.

Answer (score 5):

It causes undefined behaviour to supply a `volatile char *` to strstr.

C99 Annex J.2 (this is a list of things that undefined behaviour)

> An attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-volatile-qualified type (6.7.3)

This makes sense, as the chars might be updated during the `strstr` operation which could cause havoc.

One suggested workaround is to use a lock or other mechanism to make sure the chars will not be updated, and then copy the chars to a non-volatile buffer, and then pass that buffer to `strstr`.

Alternatively, if there is a function available to you that will safely read from the uart into a non-volatile storage area, that would work.

[Link to related SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367580/c-c-casting-away-volatile-considered-harmful)

Comment: This sounds reasonably. Even if just a non-volatile`char *`  is passed to strstr the compiler could optimize in way as if the `buf` was volatile and intentionally ignore this fact. Therefore the contents pointed by `buf` would seem to be constant, therefore not neccessary to go out of the `while` loop. This doesn't take place when the optimization is off, but it could. This is only a guess :)