# embedded c++: Initialize a volatile type structure in c++?

Tags: c++, embedded, volatile

I getting an error when I try to pass a volatile void * to memset.

What's the best way to initialize a volatile type structure in c++?

Comment: Can you share an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the error you got?

Comment: What's the code that have the problem?

Comment: For some reason it's working now. I was trying to memset(&myStructure,0,sizeof(myStructure)).  myStructure is a volatile structure type, i.e. volatile MYSTRUCTURE myStructure.

Comment: memset((void*)&myStructure,0,sizeof(myStructure)) gets rid of the error.

Comment: Casting away volatile is [undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367580/c-c-casting-away-volatile-considered-harmful) so be careful with that. It may compile but it also may have nasty side effects.

Comment: embedded.kyle: I guess I could set each element, i.e. myStructure.element1 = 0,myStructure.element2 = 0 and etc.  However, there are about 17 structures and most of them contain 20 or more elements.  memset sets each element of the structure using a pointer to the element's address, so I don't think it will be an issue.  Also, if there is an issue with casting away the volatile, there would also be an issue with using a structure that was not volatile.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, `memset` takes `void*`, not `volatile void*`.

In C++ you should use something intelligent and type-aware, like [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill).
Or, y'know, initialise your members properly using a *constructor*.